# How do I complete a proof with intersection and complements?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

For all sets $A$ and $B$, $(A \cap B)^c = A^c \cup B^c$

I am confused how complements play a role in the proof.  Can somebody explain that please.

Thank you!

Comment: depending on the flavor of proof you want, Venn diagrams are often the easiest way to go.  http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28A%27%29+intersect+%28B%27%29+venn+diagram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x \in (A \cap B)^c \rightarrow$ x $\notin$ $(A \cap B)$ $\rightarrow$ x $\notin$ (A AND B)

recall ~(A AND B) = ~(A) OR ~(B) so based on this we get

x $\notin$ (A AND B) $\rightarrow$ x $\in A^c$ OR $B^c$ here we notice all steps are reversible so it is actually double implication.

Answer (score 1):

For a set equality proof, you can either show that each set is contained in the other, or you can show that they are equal by showing that an object is a member of one of the sets if and only if it is a member of the other.

For example, one might say that:

$x \in (A \cap B)^{c} \iff x \notin A \cap B \iff ...$

Could you take it from here?

As your induction question is not related, it may be best to make this a second question.

Comment: Is there a relationship between intersection complement and union complement? I am really confused...

Comment: Yes, recall DeMorgan's law.

Comment: Okay, if I have any more questions I will be sure to ask. Thank you!

Comment: How do complements of sets play a role in the proof?